# How to display composite-in

Tags: live, composite, preview

I'm trying to display a live stream from an old fotocamera on my computer, by making use of the tv-out.

It is a composite jackit. I have also a composite portal on my pc. But I don't know how to capture from it.

Do I have to instal certain Drivers and what kind of program is easy to use to preview live my  foto camera (it works on te television, so tv-out is working)